# What is the easiest way to mimic an existing PowerPoint template using Beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations

For my thesis defense I am required to adhere to my university's official PowerPoint template. Because I have a lot of equations and PowerPoint is a pain, I would like to do my presentation using Beamer or another LaTeX-based solution. What is the easiest way to do this?

My most basic requirement is to use the same background image, while an ideal solution would preserve as many of the theme's features as possible (e.g.: fonts, bullets, decorative elements, title page, etc.).

Note: I am aware of the possibility to render equations separately and then include them in PowerPoint. This is not the kind of solution I am looking for because I like working with Beamer in particular.

Examples of design features:

Page number with short title in the lower left corner of every slide
[image: Page number with short title in the lower left corner of every slide]

Custom bullets only for the table of contents
[image: Custom bullets only for the table of contents]

Comment: The easiest for you would be to stick to powerpoint and write your equation in LaTeX with IguanaTex (windows) or Latexit (OSX) or alike.

Comment: I very much like the output that Beamer generates (especially because it's a lot easier to create highly structured presentations) and would prefer a solution that doesn't use PowerPoint.

Comment: It is very difficult to keep the horror of PPT in LaTeX :P But the background image and font styles etc. has been discussed many times here if you can search this site for `[beamer] <keyword>`

Comment: You can use the powerpoint background and decorative elements and include them using tikz. Same with the title page. For the font you should look into LuaTeX. I think it is doable, but takes some tweaking.

Answer (score 3):

> preserve as many of the theme's features as possible (e.g.: fonts,
>   bullets, decorative elements, title page, etc.).

fonts: if the font is installed in your system already compiling with Xe(La)TeX might be an option to access those fonts. `\fontspec{UniversityFontName}` Be aware that beamer is not optimized to work with XeLaTeX. (Mileage may vary.)

decorative elements: Use the `\logo{}` from beamer, it will put something as the background on each slide: `\logo{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{backgroundornaments.pdf}}` (Export an empty PowerPoint slide as pdf.)

```
\logo{% % percent signs are important, sometimes
  \makebox[\paperwidth-10pt]{%
    \includegraphics[height=0.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logoleft.eps}%
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[height=0.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logoright.pdf}%
  }%
  %\vspace{\paperheight}
}%
```

title page: Workaround: Make it in Power Point, export to .pdf and `\includegraphics[clip, width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio, page=1, viewport=33pt 54pt 682pt 459pt]{titlepageppt.pdf}` Use Ghostview or similar to find the coordinates where to crop the pdf, or crop the pdf with another tool.

Colors: The EBS uses #0D4882; as their primary color on their website. Check if this is the correct one also for the powerpoint template. Convert hex to decimal RGB values:

```
\definecolor{EBScolorRGB}{RGB}{13,72,130}
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=EBScolorRGB}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=EBScolorRGB}
```

in preamble will make your beamer color scheme more similar to the PowerPoint one.

Page Number + Short title at lower left: You might have to define your own "outer theme". Or change an existing one. `\useoutertheme{infolines}`

Comment: The background idea using the logo command works almost perfectly (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234877/how-to-adjust-the-positioning-of-a-custom-background-in-beamer). Only the alignment on the right of the slide is ever so slightly off. Any ideas to resolve this?

Comment: Meanwhile it is resolved in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234877/how-to-adjust-the-positioning-of-a-custom-background-in-beamer using `usebackgroundtemplate` and/or `\addtobeamertemplate`. The solution there is more elegant.