# How to adjust the positioning of a custom background in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer's `logo` command to use a custom background for my presentation (MWE below). While it seems to work almost perfectly, there is a little bit of whitespace to the right of the image used (the orange bar should fill up the entire width of the frame; this isn't really visible in my image below unless you open it outside of your browser window).

How can I fix this? I have attempted to insert `\hspace{}` before the `\includegraphics{}` command but this doesn't seem to work within `\logo{}`. Can I somehow "flush" the image to the right? Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{ebs.pdf}}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Beamer output]

Comment: You are scaling the image based on the height. So if the proportions of the image are not those of the frame, the image width will not equal the width of the frame. That is, to work as desired, your PDF must have a height:width ratio exactly the same as that of the paper `beamer` is using.

Comment: My background image has precisely the same width/height ratio as the output PDF file, so there must be another reason...

Comment: Could you explain why you are trying to set a custom background using `\logo{}` rather than using one of the background templates?

Comment: I got the idea here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234810/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-mimic-an-existing-powerpoint-template-using-beamer. I wasn't aware of any other options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, since you need the picture to cover the whole page, using `TiKZ` is recommended (though it requires two runs). Then you can add this picture to your template via the `\addtobeamertemplate` command. See the following implementation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{ebs.pdf}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives the required result (zoom in outside of the browser to see).

[image]

Another possibility is to use the `\usebackgroundtemplate` command in the preamble to make it global (even in title page, as asked by the OP in his comment). See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{ebs.pdf}} 

\title{The title}
\author[The author]{The Author}
\institute[Inst.]{The Institute}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}{Frame subtitle}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which now results in:

[image]

Comment: This works beautifully for all slides except the title slide and is a lot more elegant than the 'Logo' solution. Thanks! Which `beamertemplate` do I need to invoke to get the same background for my title page?

Comment: @Constantin Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Sensational! `usebackgroundtemplate` works flawlessly. Many thanks!